# Nashorn hangs inside thread

Tags: javascript, java, nashorn, javascript-engine

While running java's nashorn javascript engine inside a thread and upon the code

- engine.eval(jscript);

the application hangs. Is there something to do with thread safety? How can one run engine.eval inside a thread or callback ?

Comment: I'd assume the javascript does result in an endless loop.

Comment: the jscode is private String hwjs = "print('hello world');";

Comment: Can you post up the whole code snippet?

Comment: `private String` is not JavaScript - I'm not sure what Nashorn will do with that

Comment: @Thomas engine.eval("print('hello world')");

Comment: I see, my bad :)

Comment: I found the issue was running in a slim JVM based docker image that didn't had 'nashorn' in it.